# Как сделать свой REST API?

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest

надо сделать свой сервис API на PHP, у которого будет функционал доступа к данным в стиле REST. Используя базу данных.

Что бы работало вот так:

GET /api/games/ - список игрушек

GET /api/game/12345/ – информация о игрушке

POST /api/games/ + JSON – добавить новую игрушку

PUT /api/games/12345/ + JSON – обновить существующую игрушку

DELETE /api/games/12345/ – удалить игрушку

Данные возвращаются в JSON, с использованием как можно большего количества HTTP-статусов. Можно использовать готовые решения через composer.

Как сделать описанное мною выше, умею только получать JSON с помощью ajax, а вот как сделать свою, понятия не имею от слова совсем. Желательно какой-нибудь простенький пример с объяснениями или ссылочку где это всё простенько объясняется, опять же с примерами. Т.к. в этом деле новичок.

Comment: https://api-platform.com/

Comment: [Простой REST API в PHP - Пошаговое руководство](https://only-to-top.ru/blog/programming/2019-11-06-rest-api-php.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую Вам попробовать php фреймворк Slim.

И вот как раз обучающее видео по тому как на нем реализовать rest api:

[YouTube - Slim Framework Rest API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0p6UDIiqWEg)